# Sonata Admin: Nested sonata_type_collection error: could not get id

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

If I have a Admin class with a sonata_type_collection and the associated admin for that collection has another sonata_type_collection, trying to add a element causes the following 500 error:

```
Could not get element id from s5a033b8528778_proposals_0_services Failing part: services
```

### Steps to reproduce

```
class NegotiationAdmin extends Admin {

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $formMapper
                 ->add('proposals', 'sonata_type_collection', [
                    'required' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => 'Propuestas',
                    ], [
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'standard'
                    ]
                )
class ProposalAdmin extends Admin {

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $formMapper
            ->with('Servicios')
                ->add('services', 'sonata_type_collection', [
                    'required' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => 'Servicios ofrecidos',
                    ], [
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'standard'
                    ]
                )
```

### Expected results

Add a new element row for the field services in ProposalAdmin embedded into NegotiationAdmin

[image: example]

Clicking on the "Agregar nuevo" button under "servicios ofrecidos" makes the error happens.

### Actual results

Could not get element id from s5a033b8528778_proposals_0_services Failing part: services

I think the problem maybe is in `edit_orm_association_script.html.twig` inside DoctrineORMAdmin, which generates a wrong append url:

http://dev.aupadb.com:8888/app_dev.php/admin/core/append-form-field-element?code=admin.business.negotiation&elementId=s5a033b8528778_proposals_0_services&objectId=8&uniqid=s5a033b8528778

Because code I think should be admin.business.proposal not the id of the parent form. But I don't know how Sonata handles this.

Comment: Hey where you able to figure this out. I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Hi, finally I made a custom controller to handle this case because Sonata doen't work for this particular case...